# How to continue the build if the publishing task to Artifactory fails?

Tags: gradle, artifactory, publishing

In our project we have a publishing task to publish the jar files to jFrog artifactory.

The publishing task works fine, but if for some reason the publishing task fails, then I don't want the build to be failed.

If there a property or configuration for the publishing task to continue the build even if there was a failure?

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that you can not continue with the build if the publishing task fails.

It's not a good practice to force to continue the build in Gradle/Maven or to changue the status to SUCCES in your CI pipeline is the publishing task fails.